# How NSZombie works when it finds error on iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode

if set to on the NSZombie, it tells me that I'm releasing an object which is already released and gives me the memory address, very helpful... BUT I can't see which object it's... because the app stopped working...

any help?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for: malloc_history

http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/01/10/using-malloc-to-debug-memory-misuse-in-cocoa/

Answer (score 0):

malloc_history and my post on the same is certainly a correct answer and one way to do this.

However, it is quite likely you can do the same with Instruments, which is also going to be a bit less low level and more straightforward.   Under Xcode's `Run` menu is `Run With Performance Tool`.  Under that, you'll find `Zombies`.

Running with that, you should be able to see the type of the object being messaged and the retain/release event history.

Comment: Zombies is greyed out for me under Run With Performance Tool. I already have NSZombies enabled on my executable. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

Try Apple's http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html  utility, found in /Developer/Applications/.

A commercial alternative is  http://www.omnigroup.com/developer/omniobjectmeter/

Comment: The location you have given is no longer valid.